# How to get numeric index value for backpack crud columns?

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

Normally in the backpack crud controller we pass the column value like

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
  'name' => 'name', // The db column name
  'label' => "Username", // Table column heading
  'type' => 'Text'
]);

$this->crud->addColumn([
  'name' => 'age', // The db column name
  'label' => "Age", // Table column heading
  'type' => 'Number'
]);
```

and get the value in the backpack blade like

```
$crud->columns
```

output will come like

```
[
name: {name: "name", label: "Username", type: "Text", .....},
age: {name: "age", label: "Age", type: "Number", .....}
]
```

Above array index value are name, age. But i want it as 0, 1. How do i get index value as number?

Comment: can you please show the type of the "$crud->columns"?

Comment: It is an array. we can access this label in blade like
```
@foreach ($crud->columns as $column)
      {!! $column['label'] !!}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ok so if it is an array then we can use array_values() function which will make the index for this array 0, 1, and so on.

Comment: Now i want to access this from JavaScript like
const cols_val = {!! json_encode($crud->columns) !!};
console.log('cols_val');
It also like above.

Comment: Then use {!! json_encode(array_values($crud->columns)) !!}; or update your question for more clarity.

Comment: @sachin kumar Thanks for your answer. It works for me {!! json_encode(array_values($crud->columns)) !!}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210972/discussion-between-senthur-and-sachin-kumar).

Comment: glad it helped. Don't forget to rate up the answer, please :)

Comment: @sachin kumar  Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an array so we can use the PHP's array_values() function to re-index the array. 
like as follow.

```
array_values($crud->columns);
```

or in case of using this value in laravel blade js section then you can use as follow

```
{!! json_encode(array_values($crud->columns)) !!};
```

Ref. link:- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php